# Docker container for rails on mac is extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

Every HTTP request to my docker container takes a good 3-4 seconds. I can use the production server hosted in digital ocean and make 3-4 requests prior to one request on my local docker container.

I'm running Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4 and the latest version of Docker for Mac. Here's my `Dockerfile` file:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

COPY . /myapp

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN bundle install
```

In my current directory where this resides is my Rails application. While it boots up just fine, making any requests to `localhost:3000` takes a few seconds. I've also saw another stackoverflow post that suggested using `docker-sync` and this doesn't seem to help much, if at all.

Is there any way to just simply use my current directory as the volume for the docker container rather than copying and rsyncing back and forth?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `docker-compose` to achieve this. Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

Specify your project directory as volume for the container.